# Removing content in Parentheses at the end of a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wonder if anyone can suggest a way of stripping the parentheses (and their content inside) and the preceding space from a JavaScript string?

I'm using an iTunes XML feed and a lot of the movie titles have the year included, or "extended edition" etc.

I'd like to strip these out and just have a nice clean movie title.

Here are a couple of examples of what the string looks like now:

**Midnight Special (2016)**

**Friday (1995)**

And what I'd like it to look like after the trim.

**Midnight Special**

**Friday**

The length of the string could vary, otherwise I'd do a trim to a certain length. Many thanks in advance

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regex `/\s*\(.*\)\s*$/gm`:

```
"aaa (bb)".replace(/\s*\(.*\)\s*$/gm, ""); // "aaa"
```

```js
var str = "aaa (bb)\ncccc \nddd ()";

console.log(str.replace(/\s*\(.*\)\s*$/gm, "")); // "aaa\ncccc\nddd"
```

**Explanation:** See https://regex101.com/r/dC0aP7/2

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Pitfalls:** Be aware that this regex replaces `aa (b) and cc (d)` with `aa`.

If you only want the last parenthesis removed, use `/\s*\([^\(]*\)\s*$/gm` - which will however fail for `aa (b(c))` which is replaced with `aa (b`.

Balanced parenthesis matching is not possible with regex alone.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```
str.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)$/gm, '')
```

```js
var res = `Midnight Special (2016)

Friday (1995)`.replace(/\s*\(.+?\)$/gm, '')

console.log(res)
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/wU7kY8/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]